# Operand should contain 1 column(s) error on my sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Not sure where this is coming from. My intent is to have ROUND(AVG(duration))be divided with the difference of lead_at and qualified_at (the second subquery)

```
SELECT (SELECT first_name 
        FROM users_permissions p WHERE p.user_id=a.assistant_id LIMIT 1) as Name, (SELECT u.lead_at, u.qualified_at FROM users u INNER JOIN aircalls ON u.id=aircalls.user_id WHERE u.qualified_at - u.lead_at) AS Difference, ROUND(AVG(duration)), count(id)
FROM aircalls a
WHERE assistant_id IS NOT NULL 
AND status='Call Connected' 
AND type='user' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT u.id FROM users u INNER JOIN aircalls ON u.id=aircalls.user_id AND u.status NOT IN (1,7))
AND EXISTS (SELECT p.user_id FROM users_permissions p INNER JOIN aircalls ON p.user_id=aircalls.user_id AND p.is_agent NOT IN (1))
AND year(a.created_at)=2019
GROUP BY(SELECT first_name 
         FROM users_permissions p WHERE p.user_id=a.assistant_id LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want would help.  Your query is rather . . . weird.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I'm still not great at running large queries. 

Basically I want the average of the integer "duration" to take into account the time difference of the timestamps "u.qualified_at" and "u.lead_at", to be divided by that total.

Comment: . . You should edit the question and provide sample data and an explanation.  Your use of subqueries -- although perhaps not wrong -- is rather atypical and makes it hard to follow the logic you actually want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in your second select (difference), instead of deducing two values, you've just put them both separated by comma. Also, `where` clause in that `select` doesn't have valid value.

It was:

```
SELECT u.lead_at, u.qualified_at FROM users u INNER JOIN aircalls ON u.id=aircalls.user_id WHERE u.qualified_at - u.lead_at) AS Difference
```

Here's correction for that wrong line:

```
(SELECT u.lead_at - u.qualified_at FROM users u INNER JOIN aircalls ON u.id=aircalls.user_id) AS Difference
```